# How to disable JSON field type in H2?

Tags: mysql, json, spring-boot, hibernate, h2

I am doing database testing with `@SpringBootTest` with in-memory H2 database. I found, that `JSON` fields behave differently when created within `TestRestTemplate` and directly. The difference is not observed in `MySQL`. My fields are annotated with

```
@Column(name = "content", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "JSON")
private String content;
```

I.e. database type is `JSON` while Java type is `String`. Sometimes the content of JSON is escaped, i.e. backslashes are added before quotes.

If I mark field with `TEXT` this doesn't happen.

The question is: how to make `H2` to ignore `JSON` field type?

Setting following URL causes error:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/my_db;INIT=CREATE TYPE "JSON" AS TEXT;
```

Comment: *Sometimes the content of JSON is escaped, i.e. backslashes are added before quotes.* If you forget to unquote string value before using it in the building of JSON value then you obtain slashed doublequotes. *The difference is not observed in MySQL.* Easily... this is common problem for beginners.

Comment: *Setting following URL causes error* H2 supports JSON datatype: https://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#json_type

Comment: @Akina underlying hibernate layer behaves differently between `H2` and `MySQL`. Who is beginner of two?